# Hibernate MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Assume I have POJOs like this and i want to insert articles into MySQL database.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "article")
public class Article{
    private String author;
    private String body;
    private int commentCount;
    private List<EntryComment> comments;


@Entity
@Table(name = "comments")
public class Comment{
    private String author;
    private String body;
    private int voteCount;
```

I want to put comments in another table without deleting field `comments` from `Article. Is it possible to put Comments in separate table using hibernate annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is. I suggest that you use annotations on all elements you have @Column for the strings and int elements however for the comments just look at the code down there:

Article Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "article")
public class Article{
    private String author;
    private String body;
    private int commentCount;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "article")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
    private List<EntryComment> comments;
```

Comments Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comments")
public class Comment{

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Article article;

    private String author;
    private String body;
    private int voteCount;
```

Comment: You should not fetch eagerly article in the Comment class - this will end up with needless backward join to the article table when you will be iterating over the comments from the Article class.

Comment: I believe this will strongly depend on the application, for me it is very often the case that I need the parent object anyway when working with the a child object, so this will definitely make sense sometimes. In this post I just showed both options (from parent to child it is lazy, from child to parent it is eager). One could have left it all-toghether but I think it is important to show that it is actually possible to specify the fetch behaviour.

Comment: You're right that the comment will need the reference to its parent. But it should be lazy - in most cases you wont display anything related to article while you will be displaying comments. The article will be already displayed and what you will be interested in is displaying only the details associated with comment. When it is lazy, the article want be queried when you will be doing this. When it is eager, you will have "SELECT * FROM comment JOIN article ..." and that join with article table is needless.

Comment: This really very much depends on what kind of application stack you are using. If you are using some professional Java EE stack such as Spring in combination with webflow you basically have a phase for each request where you access the database. So it will depend on the application and the application stack for whether or not you decide for lazy or eager options. But of course I fully agree in the default case (fat client, regular Java app) a query for comment will join the article relation.